# Pine Scripe Exit Strategy after 10 bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am using V4 Pine Script and can't seem to close a strategy after e.g 10 bars. Strategy exit is as per below

```
strategy.close("buy",when = close[0]<out or close[10])
```

"Close[10]" doesn't close the strategy after 10 bars?

Comment: Pinescript requires/encourages the use of boolean expressions with logical operators. It specifies that `a or b` is true if `a` is true or `b` is true, but it doesn't specify that a number is interpreted as true, or if zero is interpreted as false (as in other languages with loose typing). I'd use `close[0]<out or not na(close[10]))`

Answer (score 0):

When you enter your strategy you can record the actual bar_index.
Then 10 bars after you will be able to close your entry :

```
var Strategy_Entry_Bar_Index = 0
if MyCondition and strategy.opentrades() == 0
    strategy.entry(......
    Strategy_Entry_Bar_Index := bar_index
if bar_index >= Strategy_Entry_Bar_Index + 10
    strategy.close_all()
```